# Edge update breaks Sharepoint Look and Feel

Tags: css, browser-compatibility

My computer was updated today and since the update my SharePoint Look and Feel was changed.  It is now a white screen with black text no matter what Look and Feel I try to select.  This is not the case if I use Internet Explorer.  If I use IE, my Look and Feel is just as it always has been.  Anyone have any idea what was broken in Edge by this update?  The same thing has also happened to someone else in my office.  Once updated, Edge is broken regarding SharePoint Look and Feel.

Comment: This seems to have to do with using the Classic Experience vs the New Experience from within Edge only.  Again, no issue if in IE.

Comment: update the IE / Edge to previous versions to confirm if the Look and Feel are broken by web browsers. There are chances that changes are triggerd by some other means

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've been able to eliminate the issue in most of my sharepoint pages by changing from Classic Experience to New Experience.  However, to fix it completely I need to update the Default Experience to be the New Experience.  I believe when I set it up I defaulted it to Classic.  I looked extensively for the setting to change the default and can't find it.  Any idea how to make that change?  I'm fine with the New Experience and using it just makes this issue go away.